# Jquery pass seelcted class content to settimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jquery loop I'm trying to pass content of selected class into the settimeout function within each loop. 
Below code is what I've tried so far.

```
$( ".success_messages" ).each(function() {
              setTimeout(function () {   
                showNotification($(this).text());                 
              }, 3000)
            });
```

How can I do it properly?

Edit: I want each iteration to delay a certain period of time based on the length of the selected class

Comment: You mean... when the user *clicks* the element, right?

Comment: `console.log(this)` inside the setTimeout callback, and see what it is.  The first step to debugging is to confirm that things are what you think they are.  Easiest way to do that is to start logging things.

Comment: Click the element or a loop based on the element length

Comment: Also your attempt to pass in the `i` to the callback and increment it is rather strange.  What are you trying to do there?  You do not appear to be using the `i` at all otherwise.

Comment: Sorry, `i` isn't used in the code I posted. I forgot to remove it.

Comment: Would be much easier if you tell what you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: @Pilan the two answers below are already addressing the original question.

Comment: So you want the messages to pop up one after another with a timepadding inbetween each?

Comment: @Taplar so you know what the task is? Please tell me!

Comment: @Pilan as the answers address, the OP was attempting to use `this` inside the setTimeout and expected it to reference the element that was clicked, not taking into account that it changes within the context of the setTimeout.  The answers address ways to go about fixing this so the correct element's text is passed into their method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do this :) Look at `each` - Found a usage for **i** aswell :D

```js
var i = 1;
$( ".success_messages" ).each(function(iterator, element) {
    setTimeout(function () {   
        // showNotification($this.text());
        console.log( $(element).text() );
    }, 1000 * i++)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='success_messages'>Message 1</div>
<div class='success_messages'>Message 2</div>
<div class='success_messages'>Message 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to show a notification when an element is clicked ([jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/click/)):

```
$(".success_messages").click(function() {
  var button = this;
  setTimeout(function() { // <-- No "i" is passed from the environment
      showNotification($(button).text());                      
      // i++; <-- WTF?!? Writing to a parameter?
  }, 3000)
});
```

The jQuery convention is that `this` is bound to the matched element when a function is run on the result of a *select* operation. The reference to that element muste be stored to be used in another function because `this` is a keyword that is rebound every time a function is **executed** and you can't generally tell what it points to by looking at the source code of a script.

Comment: Technically the `i++` is valid syntax.  I agree that it doesn't make sense though in the OP, :)

Comment: It never ever makes any sense in this universe and in the other known and unknown universes! Writing to function arguments... brrrrrr please, no!

Comment: Maybe you're iterating over elements that relate to other elements that are `'#something'+(i+1)`.  Perhaps not the best practice, but not nonsensical.

Comment: `i + 1` is not `i++` so I cannot understand your point. Rewriting arguments inside a function is pure evil and is never necessary. You can have as many local variables as you want for free

Comment: Both are performing an operation upon `i`.  As far as it being an argument vs a local variable, both are the same thing, provided you are dealing with primitives.  Both are scoped to the closure, and the changes to both do not exist outside of the closure.  And both are variables.  Variables are mutable.

Comment: I know that you know it, you know that I know it, we both know that each other knows it, so I don't mean to explain anything to you. I concede that it's technically allowed and functionally equivalent - and I think you can admit that writing to an argument should not be allowed in any sane codebase for a number of reasons that can be easily told from common sense

Comment: No, I disagree that it should not be allowed.  I have no moral objection to people doing so.  It's an available tool in a javascript programmer's toolbox.  I'll use any tool that helps me do my job.

Comment: May I ask for a sample of the usefulness of this tool? I don't miss it from my toolbox and wrote tens of thousands of lines of Javascript code

Comment: I just gave an example up above in relation to some elements relating to others, having an index one larger than their own.  Given our discussion, I highly doubt anything I provide will convince you that it should be allowed.  Which is fine.

Comment: Except that your sample does **not** overwrite the argument. Just read it to compute some string value

Comment: Which could easily be change to ++i or i = i + 1.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `this` keyword is bound to the function it is called within.

In order to be able to use it in nested function you will have to cache it first:

```
$( ".success_messages" ).each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);

    setTimeout(function (i) {   
        showNotification($this.text());                      
        i++;                  
    }, 3000)
});
```